# Preserve URI with nginx rewrite directive

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am new to nginx, I have rewrite directives to redirect hostnames to other hostnames. I want to preserve the URI in the request to the redirect so for example http://www.johntate.org/blog goes to http://johntate.org/blog and so on.

At the moment I just have this...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.johntate.org;
    rewrite / http://johntate.org/;
}
```

I want something more complicated that preserves the request and forwards it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the example on https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.johntate.org;
    return $scheme://johntate.org$request_uri;
}
```

(`$scheme` expands to `http` or `https` depending on connection type)

Have a look at the documentation at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule before asking further questions on this.

Comment: Won't I need $request_uri on the end to preserve the specific request?

Comment: @JohnTate Oops, you are correct. I was not paying attention here.